# preg_replace как удалить не нужные нули после точки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вот пример моего массива.

```
$array = ['50.100', '50.0010'];

$rule =
$replace =
$array = preg_replace($rule, $replace, $array);

$array = [50.1, 50.001];
```

Comment: сколько людей в мире говорит на английском?

Comment: @ProMix, да без разницы :Р На этом сайте говорят только на русском. Все написано в правилах ;)

Comment: а блин, я ru зашел только сейчас увидел :)

Comment: Задача не имеет смысла: `var_dump($array);` вернет `array(2) {[0]=>float(50.1)  [1]=>float(50.001)}`

Comment: ладно бы речь шла про числа в строке вида `asd 123.40 qwe`, но тут то.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать следующий пробег по массиву:

```
$array = [50.100, 50.0010];    
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
   $newArray[$key] = $val + 0;       
}
print_r($newArray); // Array ( [0] => 50.1 [1] => 50.001 )
```

В итоге в $newArray будут содержаться отформатированные значения.

**UPD** Уточнение из-за смены типов элементов с чисел на строки:

```
$array = ['55.100', '55.01', '50.001', '55.0010', '50.00'];   
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    $val = (string) ($val + 0);
}
unset($val);
var_dump($array);
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/002553e3740e39086444cfb18737820844a5a300

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [50.10000000, 50.0010000000];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Выведет:

```
50.1
50.001
```

Проблемы не существует: нули не сохраняются так и так. Нельзя удалить то, чего нет.

Comment: из чисел и так php нули уберет, тут даже foreach не нужен

Comment: Это для демонстрации.

Comment: так короче тогда$array = [50.10000000, 50.0010000000, 50.00];print_r($array);

Comment: Ваш ответ - ваши правила

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой регуляркой можете реализовать задуманное `/(.[^\.])(0+)$/`

Вот пример кода:

```
$array = [ 55.100, 55.01, 50.001, 55.0010, 50.00 ];

$rule = '/(.[^\.])(0+)$/';
$replace = '$1';
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $array[$i] = preg_replace($rule, $replace, $array[$i]);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

А это результат работы:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 55.1
   [1] => 55.01
   [2] => 50.001
   [3] => 55.001
   [4] => 50
)
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @ProMix не за что

Comment: ой, не, не работает

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 55.1
    [1] => 55.01
    [2] => 50.01
    [3] => 55.01
    [4] => 50
)

Comment: @ProMix Вы дайте исходный массив

Comment: так есть же в примере,

Comment: $array = [
    55.100, 55.01, 50.001, 55.0010, 50.00
];

Comment: @ProMix Один символ упустил в регулярке

Comment: Оно, проверил, работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

разгадал эту загадку, маиссив-то из строк

```
$array = [
    '55.100', '55.01', '50.001', '55.0010', '50.00'
];
```

регулярка

```
$pattern = '/([^\.]{0})[\.]?(0+)$/';

Array
(
    [0] => 55.100000
    [1] => 55.01
    [2] => 50.001
    [3] => 55.00100000
    [4] => 50.00000
)
Array
(
    [0] => 55.1
    [1] => 55.01
    [2] => 50.001
    [3] => 55.001
    [4] => 50
)
```

Comment: Очень подозрительную регулярку вы составили.

Comment: Ваше предложение или решение?

Comment: На этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730203/186083 посмотрите.

Comment: а где регуляное выражение, что-то не вижу?

Comment: А зачем вам тут регулярное выражение?